# Error: No instance of constructor "Faktura::Faktura" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, class, vector, function-call

I have a problem with my C++ code.

I have three classes: `Osoba` (=Person), `Produkt` (=Product) and `Faktura` (=invoice)

Osoba.h

```
class Osoba
{
 public:
     Osoba(int vek, string jmeno);
     ~Osoba();
     int vek;
     string jmeno;
};
```

Osoba.cpp

```
Osoba::Osoba(int vek, string jmeno)
{
    this->vek = vek;
    this->jmeno = jmeno;
}

Osoba::~Osoba()
{
}
```

Produkt.h

```
class Produkt
{
public:
    Produkt(int id, string jmeno, double cena);
    ~Produkt();
    string jmeno;
    double cena;

private:
    int id;
};
```

Produkt.cpp

```
Produkt::Produkt(int id, string jmeno, double cena)
{
    this->id = id;
    this->jmeno = jmeno;
    this->cena = cena;
}

Produkt::~Produkt()
{
}
```

Faktura.h

```
class Faktura
{
public:
    Faktura(int id, Osoba * osoba, vector<Produkt> produkty);

    ~Faktura();

    int CelkovaCena();

    Osoba * osoba;

    vector<Produkt> produkty;

private:
    int id;
};
```

Faktura.cpp

```
Faktura::Faktura(int id, Osoba * osoba, vector<Produkt> produkty)
{
    cout << "konstruktor Faktura" << endl;
    this->id = id;
    this->osoba = osoba;
    this->produkty = produkty;
}

Faktura::~Faktura()
{
    cout << "destruktor Faktura" << endl;
}

int Faktura::CelkovaCena()
{
    int suma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < produkty.size(); i++)
    {
        suma+=produkty[i].cena;
    }
    return suma;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Produkt * p1 = new Produkt(1, "Konvice", 450.0);
    Produkt * p2 = new Produkt(2, "Autolekarnicka", 150.0);

    Osoba * o1 = new Osoba(18,"Jakub");

    Faktura * f1 = new Faktura(1,*o1,p1);   //error

    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    delete o1;
    //delete f1;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create the "new" with Faktura in main.cpp. It gives me an error: No instance of constructor `"Faktura::Faktura" matches the argument list.`

Can you help me?

Comment: Remove a star near `o1`: `Faktura * f1 = new Faktura(1,o1,p1);`.

Comment: I tried it too, but it still gives me an error

Comment: `vector<Produkt>` is not the same as `Produkt*`.

Comment: Unlike in some other languages, in C++ you are not required to use `new` to call a constructor. `Produkt  p1(1, "Konvice", 450.0);` works just fine. And without `new` you don't need to `delete` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to match the method parameter types:

```
Faktura::Faktura(int id, Osoba * osoba, std::vector<Produkt> produkty)
```

The call has to look like this:

```
Faktura * f1 = new Faktura(1, o1, p);   //error
```

Note: `o1` is already a pointer. `p` has to be a vector.

So:

```
int main()
{
    Produkt * p1 = new Produkt(1, "Konvice", 450.0);
    Produkt * p2 = new Produkt(2, "Autolekarnicka", 150.0);

    std::vector<Produkt> p;

    p.push_back(*p1);
    p.push_back(*p2);

    Osoba * o1 = new Osoba(18,"Jakub");

    Faktura * f1 = new Faktura(1, o1, p);  

    cout <<  "Celkova cena = " << f1->CelkovaCena() << endl;

    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    delete o1;
    delete f1;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
konstruktor Faktura                                                                                                                       
Celkova cena = 600                                                                                                                        
destruktor Faktura
```

Comment: Thanks! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your constructor:
`Faktura(int id, Osoba * osoba, vector<Produkt> produkty);`, the arguments list types are: int pointer to `Osoba` and vector of `Produkt`.
You are not sending the correct parameters.
Change the second parameter to a pointer and the third one to a pointer.

Comment: You mean like this: Faktura * f1 = new Faktura(1,*o1,*p1); ? Still gives me an error

Comment: No, *p1 means the value that p1 points to. You should create a vector of `Produkt`

Answer (score 0):

You declare a pointer with `*` but you use it without it unless you want to see the content of the pointed object.

example:

```
int variable = 5;

void some_function(int *pointer_parameter) // pointer declaration
{
   // some work
}

int *pointer;            // declaration
pointer = &variable;     // usage
some_function(pointer);  // usage (you do not pass *pointer but pointer
```

So...

You defined the constructor like this:

`Faktura(int id, Osoba * osoba, vector<Produkt> produkty);`

And you are passing like this:

`Faktura(1,*o1,p1);`

However,

`o1` here does not need the star because its not a declaration.

Just do it like this:

```
Faktura * f1 = new Faktura(1,o1,p1) // the * removed from front of o1
```

Update:

But also `p1` is not a vector as the constructor expects, so you have either to define `p1` as a vector (not a pointer) or change the constructor parameter to be same type as `p1`.

C++ is a strong typed language, so all parameters have to be type-compatible with the passed values or variables.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have tried to remove the `*`, but I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods that you can use for create objects and also can use alternate each other.

```
 /* 1 */ Produkt* p1 = new Produkt ();


/* 2 */ Produkt* p2 = new Produkt;

/* 3 */ Osoba o1;
/* 4 */ Faktura f1 = Faktura::Faktura(); 

/* 5 */Produkt* p1 = new Produkt ( *new Produkt() );

/* 6 */ Produkt* p2 = new Produkt ( *new Produkt );
```

Same as before.

```
/* 7 */ Osoba* o1 = new Osoba ( Produkt foo5 );
/* 8 */ Faktura* f1 = new Faktura ( Faktura::Faktura() );
```